# Adding a Check based on a Compliance analyzer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

Here is the sample data frame (df) I'm working with:

```
+---+----+--------+
| id|orig|scrubbed|
+---+----+--------+
|  1|   a|       a|
|  2|   B|       b|
|  3|   c|       c|
|  4|   D|       d|
|  5|   *|      XX|
|  6|   $|      XX|
|  7|  ZZ|      ZZ|
|  8|  XX|      XX|
|  9|   y|       y|
| 10|   Z|       z|
+---+----+--------+
```

I'd like to perform a check that tells me whether the fraction of items that are "populated" (don't contain either "XX" or "ZZ") after scrubbing is at least 80%. (This check should fail.) I can add a Compliance analyzer to `VerificationRunBuilder` to calculate the metric, as shown here:

```
val myVerificationResult: VerificationResult = new VerificationRunBuilder(df).
    addRequiredAnalyzer(
        Compliance(
            "populatedAfterScrubbing",
            "`scrubbed` NOT IN ('ZZ', 'XX') AND `scrubbed` IS NOT NULL",
            Some("`orig` NOT IN ('ZZ', 'XX') AND `orig` IS NOT NULL")
        )
    ).
    addCheck(
        Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Review Check").
            hasSize(_ >= 1)
    ).
    run()
```

This code runs and successfully checks the data using the `hasSize` constraint, but I can't figure out how to add a constraint based on my custom Compliance analyzer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that appears to work, in case anyone is interested. The answer lies in creating a custom constraint rather than a custom analyzer. Here is the working code:

```
val myConstraint = Constraint.complianceConstraint(
    "my constraint",
    "`scrubbed` NOT IN ('ZZ', 'XX') AND `scrubbed` IS NOT NULL",
    (fraction:Double)=>fraction>=0.8,
    Some("`orig` NOT IN ('ZZ', 'XX') AND `orig` IS NOT NULL"),
    Some("no peeking")
)

val myVerificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
    .onData(df)
    .addCheck(
        Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Review Check") 
            .addConstraint(myConstraint)
    )
    .run()
}
val result = checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, myVerificationResult)
result.show(truncate=true)
```

The result is exactly as expected:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|       check|check_level|check_status|          constraint|constraint_status|  constraint_message|
+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|Review Check|      Error|       Error|ComplianceConstra...|          Failure|Value: 0.75 does ...|
+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant this be done via Check only by using statisfies https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/checks/Check.scala#L667 something like

```
Check(CheckLevel.Warning, "Statisfies TEST Constraint")      
      .satisfies("`scrubbed` NOT IN ('ZZ', 'XX') AND `scrubbed` IS NOT NULL",
                 "my constraint",
                 "fraction:Double",(fraction:Double)=>fraction>=0.8,
                  Some("..."))
      ))
```

I think this comes OOB rather than defining via complianceconstraint though that also is a good idea if you have a involved logic .